# Quarkus Kotlin init block called multiple times

Tags: kotlin, quarkus

I am trying to use Kotlin with the Quarkus framework. I need to initialize some values at application startup so I have used `init` from Kotlin and `@Startup` from Quarkus.

I do as following:

```kotlin
@Startup
@ApplicationScoped
class Initializer() {

    init {
        println("Init Variables")
    }

}
```

I expected that the string `Init Variables` would be printed only once time, but it was printed two times. It seems that Querkus initialize the same classes annotated with `@ApplicationScoped` multiple times.

I need that the initialization is executed only once otherwise I have reference trouble when I am trying to use initialized variables in the code. Is it the correct way?There is another way do that?

Comment: This is an *instance* initializer. It will be called for every new `Initializer` instance. If your application is creating two, try putting a breakpoint inside it and seeing where the calls come from.

Comment: Since the bean declares `@ApplicationScoped`, it is normal scoped and therefore a client proxy may need to be instantiated first. This is what happens here. You may want to put `@Startup` on some method instead of putting it on the class, or move the initialization code from the instance initializer to a `@PostConstruct` callback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a mix up of two approaches. In Kotlin, `init` will be called once the class is initialized, think about it as a default constructor(and if there're other constructors, they'll call this default constructor).
One option is to use `@Observes startupEvent: StartupEvent`, e.g:

```kotlin
import io.quarkus.runtime.StartupEvent
import jakarta.enterprise.context.ApplicationScoped
import jakarta.enterprise.event.Observes


@ApplicationScoped
class Initializer() {

    fun myInit(@Observes startupEvent: StartupEvent) {
        println("Init Variables")
    }
    
}
```

You can still have `init` method if you really want, since this `@Observes` will force-init the bean and this will trigger the init method.